# Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AbstractControl'. Angular Reactive Forms

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, angular-material

I am trying to push a string value into a formArray using material forms, however it is returning this error:

```
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AbstractControl'.
```

If I try and push a full object into the array it works fine, but as a string value it doesn't. This is where I declare the formArray:

```
this.maintenanceFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      title: '',
      description: ['', Validators.required],
      maintenance_images_url: this._formBuilder.array([]),
  });
```

and this is where I try and push the string value(s) into the array:

```
  const pushDownloadUrlIntoMaintenancePhotosArray = flatMap(() => {
      return this._storage.downloadURL
        .map(url => {
          console.log(url)
          const controls = <FormArray>this.formGroup.controls.maintenance_images_url;
          controls.push(url);
        });
    });
```

Any suggestion as to why I am getting this error?

Comment: Why pushing a string into FormArray which holds Controls of a form? Can you explain what is behin this._storage.downloadURL?

Comment: @jmachnik a string value for the Url of an image is being stored there

Comment: And the part with title: '' works well? Shouldn't it be title: [''] etc

Comment: `controls.push(new FormControl(url))`

Comment: Your variable name is likely confusing you. `controls` is not actually an array of controls, it is your `maintenance_images_url` FormArray. Checking the [docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray#push) shows `FormArray.push()` is expecting an AbstractControl and you are pushing a string instead.

Answer (score 1):

you should initalize your maintenance_images_url formarray, for e.g:

```
const controls = <FormArray>this.maintenanceFormGroup.controls['maintenance_images_url'];
const urlControl = this.initUrl(url);
controls.push(urlControl);

initUrl(url) {
        return this.formBuilder.group({
            value: [url],
        });
    }
```

update:

```
const controls = this.maintenanceFormGroup.get('maintenance_images_url');
if (!controls.value.includes(url)) {
  controls.push(this.formBuilder.control(url));
}
```

Comment: this is almost there but I want it to return like so: 

maintenace_images_url: [0] url

Comment: you are using FormArray and should push a formgroup to it.